# JOLT - Join nested arrays

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to join (comma separated) a nested array but cannot achieve it.

Input:

```json
{
    "PARTS" : [ [ "aaaa", "bbbb" ], [ "cccc", "dddd" ] ]
}
```

Desired output:

```json
{
    "PARTS": [ "aaaa,bbbb", "cccc,dddd" ]
}
```

I am trying to use `=join` but yet unsuccessful. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the output you were aiming for :)

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "PARTS": {
        "*": "=join(', ',@0)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The trick here is using `@0`, which points to the 0-th element on the hierarchy you're working with. At least, that's what the documentation says.